# How to write content to local disk for starlark

Tags: bazel, starlark

I want to know how to dump something (say, some string) to local disk.
I found there's `actions.write` [API](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/builtins/actions#write) , but seems it only creates an action, but not executes it.

I'm wondering how I could execute an action in starlark?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve specifically? I'd love to help, but without more context I'm not sure my answer would be useful

Comment: @ScottMinor Thanks for reply! The problem I met is oversized arguments, my intuition is to dump it to local disk, and use parameter file to load it. But later I discovered bazel already supports it (https://bazel.build/rules/lib/builtins/Args#use_param_file).

Comment: Good find! Do you want to write an answer to your own question so that I can upvote it?

Comment: @ScottMinor Sure posted.

Answer (score 1):

Bazel supports dumping parameters into a parameter file.
Doc reference: https://bazel.build/rules/lib/builtins/Args#use_param_file

Example code:

```
args.use_param_file("@%s", use_always = False)
args.set_param_file_format("multiline")
```